# Separate receiver for incoming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-call

Can we write separate broadcast receiver for incoming and outgoing calls
because I want to perform different action on incoming and outgoing call.
Is there any way to distinguish them. I tried all sort of method but it didn't work.

Comment: Using what tools? What phone? What language? It doesn't work to start the question wherever you put the needle down.

Comment: And what exactly have you tried? And how did it not work?

Comment: i have developed android address book application and i want to syn the incoming and outgoing number separately to the server.

Comment: Why do all the Android programmers just assume *everyone knows* they're writing an Android program?

Comment: @ cody Gray if you have any suggestions then only reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class extend the **PhoneStateListener** where you should **onCallStateChanged** method. Once the phone state changes to **TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE** you can parse the  call log:

```
final String[] callsProjection = new String[] { Calls.TYPE, Calls.DURATION, Calls.DATE, Calls.NUMBER };
final Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Calls.CONTENT_URI, callsProjection, null, null, Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

Once you have that info, you can easily check the last entry for the call type:

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int idType = cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.TYPE);
        if(t == Calls.INCOMING_TYPE) {            
        } else if (t == Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE) {
        } else { /* missed call */ }
    }
    cursor.close();
```

***NOTE:*** Before parsing the call log you might want to wait a few seconds (3 should be enough), just to be sure the information gets written in the log!

Comment: thanks..but can i do this during a call.Does the entry goes immediately in call log when call is initiated

Comment: Nope, it does not. The entry will get into the log after the call ended (a few seconds after that actually).